# How to configure the Windows 802.1x authentication using powershell script

Tags: windows, ui-automation, powershell-3.0

I need suggestions/steps for developing Powershell Scripts through GUI approach configure  802.1x/PEAP se authentication settings in windows 10.

Comment: What do you mean with "GUI approach" with powershell?

Comment: @JamesZ GUI approach >> it should prompt windows while executing the script.